# How to draw segments (geom_segment) dynamically in R ggplot?

Tags: r, dynamic, ggplot2, data-visualization

Given a fixed set of points, I can plot them and add explicit code to connect some of them with geom_segment. If I had a separate data source with all segments' coordinates, is there a way to add a loop for these segments in same plot?

```
    ggplot() + 
      geom_point(data=cm,mapping = aes(x, y)) +
      # connect every two paired assets based on separate data source
      geom_segment (mapping=aes(x=10,y=10,xend=100,yend=100), arrow=arrow(angle = 8,type ="closed",length = unit(0.10, "inches")), 
size=0.2, linetype=1, color="#cccccc")
+ geom_segment ( ...
```

Data set:

```
x,y
10.0, 10.0
100.0, 100.0
...
```

Segments:

```
x,y,x2,y2
10.0, 10.0, 100.0,100.0
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass a different data source for each geom. In this case:

```
ggplot() + 
      geom_point(data = cm, aes(x, y)) +
      geom_segment(data = segment, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = x2, yend = y2),
                   arrow = arrow(angle = 8,type = "closed",length = unit(0.10, "inches")), 
                   size = 0.2, 
                   linetype = 1,  
                   color = "#cccccc")
```